# 'findmnt --verify' gives warning: 'cannot detect on-disk filesystem type'

Tags: linux, mount

I used `findmnt --verify` to verify some changes I did to `/etc/fstab`. However to my surprise it gave me the warning

```
/
   [W] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type
```

for my root partition. A quick check with `df -T /` shows

```
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2      ext4 116778960 107259980   3543840  97% /
```

Is the `on-disk filesystem type` something different from the filesystem type of the partition?

If not, is the warning legit or a missing feature/bug? (`findmnt --version` gives `findmnt from util-linux 2.31.1`)

Comment: What does `mount` say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the `on-disk filesystem type` something different from the filesystem type of the partition?

No.

> is the warning legit or a missing feature/bug?

Legit but somewhat misleading. It could be `findmnt: /dev/sdb2: Permission denied`.

Regular users cannot read `/dev/sdb2` directly, so the tool cannot verify if the device holds a filesystem that matches the corresponding `fstab` entry. Run `sudo findmnt --verify`. The tool will be allowed to examine `/dev/sdb2`.

Comment: Seems exactly right. `strace -f findmnt --verify 2>&1 | grep "/dev/sdb2"` gives `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`, which shows that `findmnt` is indeed trying to open that file. When I execute the same command with sudo the sys call succeeds.

Comment: Can't believe that something so simple as not using `sudo` was causing the error. This did the trick, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The next version (v2.38) will print the reason, for example

`[W] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type (Permission denied)`